# when I run this program, and type in the command line: run BinarySearch tinyW.txt<tinyT.txt. It returns a memory location, I do not know why

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] whitelist = In.readInts(args[0]);

    Arrays.sort(whitelist);

    StdOut.println(whitelist);
    while(!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {
      int key = StdIn.readInt();
      if (rank(key, whitelist) < 0)
        StdOut.println(key);
    }
  }

  public static int rank(int key, int[] a)
  {
    return rank(key, a, 0, a.length-1);
  }

  public static int rank(int key, int[] a, int low, int high)
  {
    if (low > high) return -1;
    int mid = low + (high - low)/2;
    if      (key < a[mid]) return rank(key, a, low, mid - 1);
    else if (key > a[mid]) return rank(key, a, mid + 1, high);
    else                   return mid;
  }
}
```

Comment: > java BinarySearch tinyW.txt

Comment: The expected out put should be: 50 99 13 instead it returns:           > [I@1484a8a

Comment: The code is copied straight from the book, so I don't think there's any thing wrong with it

Comment: @help:I know your username reflects the tone of your posts, but you need to start doing more than just dumping your code on us.

Comment: I am not asking for the solution to the code, the code is perfely fine, but I think my class path is not set correctly. I am using doctor java. Not sure if this has any thing to do with it.

Comment: Also, better add all the additions to the question really to the question, instead of comments. There is an edit link for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know your `StdIn`, `In` and `StdOut` classes (these are not in the standard Java distribution).

But the reason for your output is this line:

```
StdOut.println(whitelist);
```

This will probably simply call `whilelist.toString()`, and the `toString()` method for arrays outputs something like you showed (`[I` stands for `int[]`, and `1484a8a` is something like a memory address, yes.)

If you want to print the contents of the array, use

```
StdOut.println(Arrays.toString(whitelist))
```

instead, or use a loop.

Comment: do any body know how to pass a text file as an input?

Comment: I think doctor java doesn't know what this command line does: tinyT.txt < tinyW.txt

Comment: On the command line, (i.e. cmd.exe on Windows) it should work with the redirections `< ...` (read stdin from file) and `> ...` (write output to file). I don't know Doctor Java, though.

Comment: I am planning to do it on the windows command line, do anyone know how to open java file in the command line?